# Spring boot edit json exception with data from server response

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, error-handling

My spring boot application works like a middleman. It waits for a request, then formats this request and sends to the server and returns server response to request sender. However when I get response error response from server (For example with status code 400 Bad Request) I want to modify default spring boot JSON exception body by adding error cause which was returned from server in JSON format.

Response from server:

```
Http status: 400
{
    "type": "InvoiceDto",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "error_code": "NO_AMOUNT"
    "error_message": "amount is not set"
    "invoice_status": "FAILED",
    "payment_id": "20516324",
    "order_id": 1209,
  }
```

Spring boot returns exception:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1493211638359,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException",
  "message": "400 Bad Request",
  "path": "/sms"
}
```

I want to edit spring's exception field "message" with server's returned "error_message" value. But it seems that I can't even get Response body because spring boot automatically throws default exception.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you need to provide your own exception mapper. The one used now is the default `ErrorController` added by autoconfiguration.

The correct way is to define your own `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

you can read about custom Exceptionmappers [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling)