# SpringBoot capture requestBody on error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an app that is accepting some JSON. It has a controller with @RestController and then a

```
@RequestMapping(value="/junk", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public MyResponse postInfo(@RequestBody MyRequest info) {
...
}
```

This "works" in that it accepts JSON that is valid as per the "MyRequest" object and handles it. I am interested in capturing the times when the JSON is not valid.

Currently what happens when there's bad data is Spring seems to write something like this to stdout:

```
2017-04-26 13:57:40.621  WARN 13537 --- [pr-8080-exec-13] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@cc73b4; line: 1, column: 1048800]
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@cc73b4; line: 1, column: 1048796] (through reference chain: com.junk.ProcessInfo["process_list"]->java.util.ArrayList[4692]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@cc73b4; line: 1, column: 1048800]
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@cc73b4; line: 1, column: 1048796] (through reference chain: com.junk.ProcessInfo["process_list"]->java.util.ArrayList[4692])
```

This is all well and good, but I want to see what the request was that was bad so I can go fix it on the source side.

I was playing with writing a "ControllerAdvisor" like

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class ControllerAdvisor {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @ModelAttribute
    public void logBody(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String requestString) {
        logger.trace("requestString" + requestString);
    }
}
```

which seems to write out the request body of every request (not just errors) but when I use this, it seems to modify the request such that the actual controller will fail with

```
2017-04-26 14:28:31.432  WARN 523 --- [io-8081-exec-29] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public com.junk.MyResponse com.junk.ProcessController.postInfo(com.junk.MyRequest)
```

I was also playing with Actuator, but Actuator.trace doesn't actually give me the body.

Is there any way to get the actual requestBody inside my RestController?

Edit: Here's a complete app that demonstrates the behavior:

[Download example](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mbwebhostbucket/spring-example.tar.gz)

Comment: The issue here is that you are reading the RequestBody first in the Controller Advice and attempting to read it again in the actual controller... but since the input stream is already used up from the controller advice it fails

Answer (score 0):

From what the log says it's not an issue with your server side implementation. From the log I interpret it as you posted a JSON body like this:

```
{
    myPropert: myvalue
}
```

when the message converter is expecting:

```
{
    "myPropert": "myvalue"
}
```

Comment: No, it's working fine when the json is properly formatted.  Basically I put like { "junk" : "value" }. It shows in the output but then it fails as if the body is null or something

Comment: Have you tried adding a `@ExceptionHandler` in your `@ControllerAdvice`?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635137/spring-boot-edit-json-exception-with-data-from-server-response/43636028#43636028

Comment: Yes, but with ExceptionHandler, you tell it to get HttpRequestServlet but then can't call getInputStream or getReader. It seems like springframework does getInputStream and so when it gets here, the stream is already closed.